# Match a string that includes a space in Helm

Tags: search, helm

I find Helm's space separated queries very useful.

However, on occasion, particularly while using the `@` prefix (searching for match within a buffer in helm-mini) I would like to be able to specify a single search string which includes a space.

E.g. `@Find\ buffer\ matching\ this\ text`

Is this possible?

Comment: Any chance you could just enter a space literal with `C-q` followed by `<space>`?

Comment: @Dan I think that requires an extra key press compare with escape character.

Comment: @TuDo Thanks for opening the ticket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible. I opened an issue [here](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/issues/660).

Edit: It's not possible.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to search names with spaces using \\ escaping.
For example if there are two buffers opened, one named "file with spaces" and the second named "filewithoutspaces", then, in helm-mini, pattern "with spaces" will find both buffers, while pattern "with spaces \\ " (note the space at the end) will find only the buffer with space in name.

Still, I cannot find a way to search with space in buffer contents.

Comment: Using @kwas's answer, I was able to find a way to do this: `\.ID\\ =` appears to be an effective way to search for the flat string `.ID =`.